# Copy Excel data to Word after Office 2016 upgrade from 2010

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

We copy data from Excel cells to a new Word document based on a .docx template document. The positioning in the Word document is found with a bookmark.

The VBA code has been working, but since upgrading to MS Office 2016 from 2010 we have been getting errors:

> run time error 4605 this method or property is not available because
>   the clipboard is empty or not valid

And then I get

> 4605 This method or property is not available because this command is
>   not available for reading

I tried the `wdDoc.Bookmarks…` and I get

> 6124 You are not allowed to edit this selection because it is
>   protected

I checked all the protection, trust center settings, etc. and all look correct.

"editProject" is a single cell label.

```
Dim wdApp   As Object
Dim wdDoc   As Object
Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.application")
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(Filename:=WdocT, ReadOnly:=True)

' Project NAME
wdDoc.Bookmarks("BOOKMARK1").Range.Select '     wdDoc.Bookmarks("CLIENT").Range.Select
xlData = Sheets("Data Input").Range("editProject") ' get the data

'THIS IS THE PROBLEM LINE
wdApp.Selection.TypeText Text:=xlData ' place in doc '8/10/19 FALLING OVER HERE
```

I know the doc is opening, and the bookmark is found, as I put in the following to check:

```
'temp TRY THIS
Dim tempRange As Word.Range
Dim tempStart As Long
Dim tempEnd As Long
'   Set tempRange = wdDoc.Bookmarks("BOOKMARK1").Range
Set tempRange = wdDoc.Bookmarks("BOOKMARK2").Range ' THIS WORKS
tempStart = tempRange.Start
tempEnd = tempRange.End
```

I tried clearing the clipboard with the following:

```
' 8/10/19 Bruce the following may help with clipboard error message 4605
wdDoc.UndoClear
Dim oData As New DataObject ' object to use the clipboard
oData.SetText Text:=Empty ' clear
oData.PutInClipboard ' take in the clipboard to empty it
'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")) ' this is required to stop clipboard overflow error
Application.CutCopyMode = False ' 8/10/19 Bruce - this should clear the clipboard
DoEvents ' test fixing error 4605
' DoEvents passes control to the operating system.
' Control is returned after the operating system has
'  finished processing the events in its queue
```

I tried the following in the appropriate place, but it makes no difference:

```
Dim wdApp   As Word.Application
Dim wdDoc   As Word.Document
wdApp.Visible = True
```

I tried the following line instead of the copy, but the same error is thrown;

```
wdApp.Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
```

Comment: I might be missing something but I don't see where in your code you either copy or paste something, so I'm not sure why the focus is on the clipboard?  Reading a cell value and then writing that value to a word bookmark doesn't use the clipboard.  What is the error message you're getting?  Have you tried using something like `wdDoc.Bookmarks("BOOKMARK1").Range.Text = xlData` ?  No need to select anything here

Comment: Is "editProject" a single-cell range?

Comment: I'm curious where you found the clipboard theory.  Every thing I'm finding indicates you are attempting to modify an object that doesn't exist or is not editable.  Do you have a specific need that requires using`Selection`? If not, I would try  replacing it with `Range`.

Comment: I'd say the problem is that `Selection` is unable to accept what's being done to it. If you use ` wdDoc.Bookmarks("BOOKMARK1").Range.Text = xlData` instead of first selecting the bookmark then trying to type text to it, what happens?

Comment: The error code was "run time error 4605 this method or property is not available because the clipboard is empty or not valid", but now I am getting "4605 This method or property is not available because this command is not available for reading". I tried the "wdDoc.Bookmarks..." and I get "6124 You are not allowed to edit this selection because it is protected". I have checked all the protection, trust center settings etc and all look correct.
"editProject" is a single cell label.

Comment: One very important thing for replying in comments: You *must* prefix the screen name of the person you're target use the @ symbol, otherwise you can't be sure that person will get a notification. I'm only just seeing this because sometimes I check back... @cindymeister, for example

Comment: It sounds to me as if the "bookmarks" you're targeting may actually be ***form fields***? And that Forms protection has been activated for the Word document? Can you write anywhere you please in that document, or will it only let you write in certain areas?

Comment: @BMac in your example you use BOOKMARKS1 but in your test you use BOOKMARKS2 and you state it works.  So is it 1 or 2.  I could not recreate the issue using your code

Comment: @Sorceri the doc as bookmark1 and bookmark2 in it, I was just testing the second one also.

Comment: @cindymeister I can write anywhere in the doc if I open it in word. Please note that this was all working fine until an office upgrade.

Comment: I know I've said, others have said it, maybe I missed it but I don't see where you tried following the suggestion of not using selection.  What happens when you use range instead?

Answer (score 0):

If Excel General setting "Open e-mail attachments and other uneditable files in reading view" is NOT ticked, it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar issue after my environment was upgraded to Office 2016. The code I had was working perfectly before the upgrade.

One thing I noticed later was that, after the upgrade to Office 2016, the same VBA code that used to work would open a Word doc in the "reading mode". In this mode, no editing of the document is allowed, no matter via the UI or via code. This is the meaning of the cryptic error message "4605 This method or property is not available because this command is not available for reading".

To get around this, I added the following line to make Word switch back to the "Print layout view".

```
objWord.ActiveWindow.View.Type = wdPrintView
```

where `objWord` is the Word object created by code not listed here.

Then I can use my old code like these to type text via VBA:

```
objWord.Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:=bookmarkName
objWord.Selection.TypeText Text:=someText
```

So if you notice your VBA code happens to open a Word doc in the "Reading mode", you can try this work around.

A similar situation is described at this link and I came across it after I found my work around:

https://blogs.msmvps.com/wordmeister/2013/02/22/word2013bug-not-available-for-reading/